# Will validators get extra profit from executing ewasm contracts?

Tags: ewasm

1. Do I need to run special node for executing ewasm contracts?
2. Will my TEKU node able to run it?
3. If 2 (Yes) Will I get extra ETH apart from staking for executing ewasm contracts?
4. if 3 (Yes) how much?